# Arrange $6$ people in $4$ rooms such that each room has $1$ or $2$ people

Tags: combinatorics

> **Problem.** In a hotel, four rooms are available. Six persons are to be accommodated in these four rooms in such a way that each of these rooms contains at least one person and at most two persons. Then the number of all possible ways in which this can be done is

I have already seen the answer on Google, but I tried it with a different approach

$$ \binom{6}{4} \cdot 4! \cdot \binom{4}{2} \cdot 2! $$

Select $4$ people from the group of $6$, now we have $4!$ ways of arranging them in $4$ rooms.

Now select any $2$ rooms from $4$.

Now there are $2!$ Ways of arranging the $2$ people left from the group of $6$.

My answer is $4320$(thanks @A.C. and @peterwhy for pointing out), but the correct answer is $1080$.

Where am I overcounting?

Comment: Does your version give the same number as does the google result? Also you should cite the google result here so users can check it.

Comment: Even for your mentioned "C(6,4)•4!•C(4,2)•2!", that gives $15\cdot24\cdot 6\cdot 2 = 4320 \ne 2160$.

Answer (score 3):

First, the result of the formula you did is 4320, not 2160.

The way you are overcounting is:

For every actual case, assume that there are two people A and B in the first room. You counted it twice: once with A in the first four people and B in the other two, another time with B in the first four people.

There are two rooms with two people, and you are overcounting by a factor of 2 for each room. So you are overcounting by a factor of 4 in total.

Comment: So the rooms where 2 people occupy it, I am counting their permutations too but they result in identical arrangement.ex 1,2,34,56 and 1,2,43,56 and 1,2,34,65 and 1,2,43,65  are all different permutation but result in identical arrangement. So we divide by 4. Is that all or I am still missing something

Comment: @AIŚVARYASINGH That's all.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been mentioned, you are overcounting.

If you are familiar with the multinomial coefficient, it provides a neat mechanical way for such problems, viz

$[Lay\;down\;pattern]\times [Permute\;pattern]$

$= \frac{6!}{1!1!2!2!}\times \frac{4!}{2!2!} =1080$

**Added**

The multinomial coefficient has three equivalent forms, eg for laying down patterns, $\Large\binom{6}{1,1,2,2},\;$(classical) $\;\binom61\binom51\binom42\binom22,\;$(teams) and $\; \frac{6!}{1!1!2!2!},$ *(permutations)*